# jQuery callback if element found

Tags: jquery

I have tried the following code:

```
$('a.buildMenu').click(function (event) {

                    // Prevent normal behaviour
                    event.preventDefault();

                    // Stops it bubbling to the document
                    event.stopPropagation();

                    var link = $(this);

    $(document).find('div#' + $(link).data('id'), function() {

                            console.log($(link).data('id'));
                            $('.buildMenu').removeClass('selected');
                            $('.menu').remove();
                            return false;
                        });
```

Which basically means if a div with an id that matches the value of `data-id` on the clicked link then run the code. However the find method has no callback. How would I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to wait for anything, right? So just use an if-statement:

```
var $elements = $('div#' + link.data('id'));

if ($elements.length > 0) {
    console.log(link.data('id'));
    $('.buildMenu').removeClass('selected');
    $('.menu').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
if($(document).find('div#' + $(link).data('id')).length){
    $('.buildMenu').removeClass('selected');
    $('.menu').remove();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an if statement -

```
   if  ($(document).find('div#' + $(link).data('id')).length) {
      console.log($(link).data('id'));
      $('.buildMenu').removeClass('selected');
      $('.menu').remove();
   });
```